# How to connect a local server to multiple computers via Ethernet cable WITHOUT Internet?

Tags: server, localhost, router, lan

I have a windows machine that has a local WAMP server running without the Internet. I would need to connect a few Mac computers to that local server via Ethernet cable stream some video content.

I kind of know that I would need a router to connect all to Mac computers and a server computer. I am still not clear how to do it without the Internet.

Any Help would be really appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to just get an ethernet switch (something like [this](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833122128&cm_re=ethernet_switch-_-33-122-128-_-Product)) and connect everything.  You would then just reference your server in a browser or other app by it's IP address or computer name instead of a www address.

Answer (score 0):

What you are talking about is soomthing called a peer-to-peer setup. See this [Setting up a Peer to Peer Network](http://www2.southeastern.edu/Academics/Faculty/nadams/etec650/peertopeer.html)